# PC BIOS and VGA BIOS interconnection

Tags: vga

I have 386 PC clone computer with BIOS EPROM. And I have VGA ISA board with it's own EPROM BIOS. I want to know how main BIOS interconnects with VGA BIOS.

Does main BIOS calls (jumps to execute) VGA BIOS after computer powered on ? If not how `int 10h` interrupts are connected with VGA BIOS.